# Value in where cannot be cast to type :id in query

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I’m trying to join my comments to a post, so that when a user visits /posts/:id/comments, he/she can get to view all the comments associated with the post.

This is my router

```
resources "/posts", PostController, except: [:new, :edit] do
   resources "/comments", CommentController, except: [:new, :edit]
end
```

Then my Post Controller:

```
def index(conn, _params) do
    post = Posts.list_posts()
    render(conn, "index.json", posts: posts)
end

def create(conn, post_params) do
    with {:ok, %Post{} = post} <-Posts.create_post(post_params) do 
       #create_post is from post context
    conn
    |> put_status(:created)
    |> put_resp_header("location", post_path(conn, :show, post))
    |> render("show.json", post: post)
  end
end

def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    post = Repo.get!(Post, id)
    comment_changeset = Comment.changeset(%Comment{})
    render(conn, "show.json", post: post, comment_changeset: 
    comment_changeset)
end
```

My comment controller:

```
def index(conn, _params) do
    comment= Comment.list_comment() #from comment context
    render(conn, "index.json", comments: comments)
end

def create(conn, comment_params) do
    post = Repo.get(Post, comment_params)
    comment_changeset = Ecto.build_assoc(post, :comment, 
    comment_params)
    Repo.insert(comment_changeset)

    conn
    |> put_status(:created)
    |> render("show.json")
end

def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  comment = Comment.get_comment!(id) #from comment context
  render(conn, "show.json", comment: comment
end
```

When I try to add new comment in post/:id/comments, it throws this error:

```
(Ecto.Query.CastError) deps/ecto/lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:348: value 
`%{"description" => "bitcoin", "post_id" => "2", "name" => "ethereum"}` 
in `where` cannot be cast to type :id in query:

from m in Myapp.Posts.Post,
 where: p.id == ^%{"description" => "bitcoin", "post_id" => "2", "name" 
=> "ethereum"},
  select: p
```

This is my Myapp.Posts.Post:

```
schema "posts" do
    field :description, :string
    field :name, :string
    has_many :comments, Myapp.Comments.Comment
    field :body, :string

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
 def changeset(post, attrs) do
    post
    |> cast(attrs, [:name, :description, :body])
    |> validate_required([:name, :body ])
 end
```

And my Myapp.Comments.Comment

```
 schema "comments" do
    field :description, :string
    field :name, :string
    belongs_to :market, Myapp.Posts.Post

    timestamps()
 end

  @doc false
 def changeset(comment, attrs) do
    pair
    |> cast(attrs, [:name, :description])
    |> validate_required([:name, :description])
 end
```

From the error, I think ecto is trying to pass the entire request parameters as p.id, but it shouldn’t be so, please how can I correct it? I have done many researches on it and tried some changes but got different errors.

Comment: This was my initial Comment Controller: `def create(conn, %{"post_id" => id, "comment_params" =>  comment_params}) do
    post = Repo.get(Post, id)
    comment_changeset = Ecto.build_assoc(post, :comment, comment_params)
    Repo.insert(comment_changeset)                                                                  
`But this gave me this error: `[debug] ** (Phoenix.ActionClauseError) could not find a matching MyappWeb.CommentController.create clause. This typically happens when there is a parameter mismatch but may also happen when any of the other
action arguments do not match.`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
Repo.get(Post, comment_params)
```

Comment params is what the controller receives, and this is what you see in your error message:

```
%{"description" => "bitcoin", "post_id" => "2", "name" => "ethereum"}
```

OTOH [`Repo.get/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:get/3) expects the post id as the second field. Something like this would work:

```
def create(conn, %{"post_id" => id} = comment_params) do
  post = Repo.get(Post, String.to_integer(id))
```

Comment: I tried but got new error when posting to posts/:id/comments: `**(FunctionClauseError) no funtion clause matching in Ecto.drop_meta/1`

Comment: This is something different and completely unrelated to the original question. You might probably post another question asking for this issue, specifying what data do you post, what line this error comes from and all that stuff.